# UnicodeDecodeError while processing Accented words

Tags: python, yaml, python-3.6, pyyaml

I have a python script which reads a YAML file (runs on an embedded system). Without accents, the script runs normally on my development machine and in the embedded system. But with accented words make it crash with

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

only in the embedded environment.

The YAML sample:

```
data: ã
```

The snippet which reads the YAML:

```
with open(YAML_FILE, 'r') as stream:
  try:
    data = yaml.load(stream)
```

Tried a bunch of solutions without success.

Versions: Python 3.6, PyYAML 3.12

Comment: That snippet doesn't read the YAML document from a file, it has syntax errors (no `except`), `YAML_FILE` is undefined and `yaml` not imported. Always post complete minimal examples, it is difficult enough to reproduce questions like this without knowing and/or having access to the embedded system. Make it easy on the answerers, it is for your own benefit. And you can probably get this error without even trying to load the as YAML, just reading the file should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codec that is reading your bytes has been set to ASCII. This restricts you to byte values between 0 and 127.

The representation of accented characters in Unicode, comes outside this range, so you're getting a decoding error.

A UTF-8 codec decodes ASCII as well as UTF-8, because ASCII is a (very small) subset of UTF-8, by design.

If you can change your codec to be a UTF-8 decode, it should work.

In general, you should always specify how you will decode a byte stream to text, otherwise, your stream could be ambiguous.

Comment: This principle of UTF-8 everywhere is a good general internationalisation recommendation, whatever technology you are using.

The present draft of HTML5.3 is driving towards only supporting UTF-8

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. It worked for loading the file using utf-8 encoding. But after, when I try to access a key in the dict, the same error is thrown.

Comment: Although that suggests another UTF-8 error, it's difficult to guess exactly what's happening. I suggest that you make this into another question, with its own specific details.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the codec that should be used when dumping data using PyYAML, but there is no way you specify your coded in PyYAML when you load. However PyYAML will handle unicode as input and you can explicitly specify which codec to use when opening the file for reading, that codec is then used to return the text (you open the file as text file with `'r'`, which is the default for `open()`).

```
import yaml

YAML_FILE = 'input.yaml'

with open(YAML_FILE, encoding='utf-8') as stream:
    data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
```

Please note that you should almost never have to use `yaml.load()`, **which is documented to be unsafe**, use `yaml.safe_load()` instead.

To dump `data` in the same format you loaded it use:

```
import sys
yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, allow_unicode=True, encoding='utf-8',
               default_flow_style=False)
```

The `default_flow_style` is needed in order not to get the flow-style curly braces, and the `allow_unicode` is necessary or else you get `data: "\xE3"` (i.e. escape sequences for unicode characters)