# readlines and numpy loadtxt gives UnicodeDecodeError after upgrade 18.04

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu

I have a python script which uses `readlines` and `numpy.loadtxt` to load a csv file. It works perfectly fine on my desktop running ubuntu 16.04. On my laptop running 18.04 I get (loading the same file) the following error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 446: invalid start byte`

What can I do to make the script working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError while processing Accented words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720614/unicodedecodeerror-while-processing-accented-words)

Comment: If possible, I would like to understand why it worked in Ubuntu 16.04 and stopped working in 18.04

Comment: I wonder if the `encoding` parameter to `loadtxt` would help.

Comment: Was there a change in the Python or `numpy` versions as well?

Comment: Or possibly default platform encoding may be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` to `readlines` and `loadtxt` did the trick.